# Usb tethering not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: internet, usb-modem, easytether

I had fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday,  before  i use to connect  mobile  to pc and after enabling usb tethering,  internet gets connected
But now mobile gets detected in system,  but no internet connected or no wired connection exist.

Please tell me , how do i connect internet in system ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

try 
sudo apt install macchanger -y

sudo machchanger -r "usb-interface or ens20en22 look {ip a}"

USB DEBUG

for me, Samsung s9 not working

Comment: is it worked for you ?

Comment: The problem was in Samsung Firmware after update to G960FOXM9ETF2 it fixes the problem. Thank you for your replay.

Comment: I suppose second command should be "sudo macchanger" instead of "sudo machchanger".
However this command doesn't work for me.